# How to use Keyboard input in Qt5 for Execution of function xyz?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

i am doing some experiments on Keyboard Input in Qt5 and now after I did some research I couldn't find a simple way to execute Code if a specific button is pressed e.g. Button R. Now my Question is which way is the most simple to use the Keyboard Input (real Keyboard, not virtual Keyboard) to do things.

I would really appreciate some help or even examples on this :)

Greetings
Lybbo

Comment: Do you have a GUI?

Comment: Yes there is a GUI with the QMainWindow class.

Answer (score 3):

Just override in your class `QWidget::keyPressEvent` method. You can recieve pressed key from `QKeyEvent *event` argument using `QKeyEvent::key` method.

Simple example below:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QKeyEvent>

class MyClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0):QWidget(parent){}

protected:
     void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override
     {
         if(event->key() == Qt::Key_R)
         {
             //Do something when 'R' key is pressed
         }
     }
};
```

You can find more informations in [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent).

Comment: thank you I'll take a look at it :)